# How do I find the name of an album from the cd?

Tags: compact-disc

I was going to write a script which checks the currently entered cd against a list of albums. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but I don't know how to get the album's name from its cd. I know this is possible, because I can view the name in Windows Media Player.

Comment: `because I can view the name in Windows Media Player.`. you forgot to add `but only when my PC is connected to the Internet so it could look things up`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [CDEX](http://cdex.mu/). Its easy to use and integrated with FreeDB for disc info. FreeDB only works for copies or original CD's.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do what I wanted with java-avm. This might not be too much help if you just want to see it rather than code something with it though :/